# When used inside a function, transform.zoo can't access variables

Tags: r, function, zoo

I found out that zoo's `transform` is not able to use additional (i.e. not part of the zoo object) variables *when used in a function body*.

Let me explain:

I entered the following code at the prompt to create a small two-column zoo object `z` and to add a new column calculated from an existing column and a variable `x`:

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(matrix(1:10, ncol=2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("a", "b"))), order.by=2001:2005)
x <- 2
transform(z, c = x*a)
```

I got the desired result, a zoo object with a new colum `c`.  No problem here.

Now I'd like to use `transform` in a function body; the variable for the calculation is passed as a parameter to the function:

```
rm(x)
f <- function(data, x) { transform(data, c = x*a) }
f(z, 2)
```

This stops with `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) (from #1) : object 'x' not found`. If I assign `x <- 2` at the prompt, it works (therefore the `rm(x)` above).

With dataframes (i.e. `transform.data.frame`) there is no problem.

I think that when `transform.zoo` calls `transform.data.frame`, the bindings of the formals of `f` are lost.   I don't understand R's environments well enough to find out what exactly is wrong here.

Edited to add: Not only can `transform` not get the formals but also no variables from inside the function body.

Is there a way to make `transform` see `x`? (I know I could work without transform, but it's a nice tool for short, succinct code.)

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Here is a workaround: `f <- function(data, x) zoo(transform(as.data.frame(data), c = x*a), index(data))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I wonder if the issue is the additional levels of frames in Florian's example because they are using `transform.zoo`, which calls `transform.data.frame` eventually, whereas your example now only goes so far as `transform.data.frame`. It may be difficult to make this work in a function as `transform()` doesn't allow you to change the `envir` and `enclos` arguments of the resulting `eval()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best advice is: **Don't do that!**

`transform()`, `with()`, `subset()` are really sugar for use at the top level, to make things somewhat easier to write data manipulation code. If you are writing functions you should use the general replacement functions `[<-` and `[[<-` depending on what you are doing.

If you don't believe me, see the *Warning* in `?transform`

> ```
> Warning:
>
>     This is a convenience function intended for use interactively.
>     For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting
>     arithmetic functions, and in particular the non-standard
>     evaluation of argument ‘transform’ can have unanticipated
>     consequences.
> ```

What I mean by using `[<-` or `[` or other functions is to write `f` like this

```
f <- function(obj, x) {
  cd <- coredata(obj)
  cd <- cbind(cd, c = x * cd[, "a"])
  zoo(cd, index(obj), attr(obj, "frequency"))
}

f(z, 2)
```

Which gives the desired result

```
> transform(z, c = x*a)
     a  b  c
2001 1  6  2
2002 2  7  4
2003 3  8  6
2004 4  9  8
2005 5 10 10
> f(z, 2)
     a  b  c
2001 1  6  2
2002 2  7  4
2003 3  8  6
2004 4  9  8
2005 5 10 10
```

`f` is complicated because `coredata(obj)` is a matrix. It might be neater to

```
f2 <- function(obj, x) {
    cd <- as.data.frame(coredata(obj))
    cd[, "c"] <- x * cd[, "a"] ## or cd$c <- x * cd$a
    zoo(cd, index(obj), attr(obj, "frequency"))
}

f2(z, 2)

> f2(z, 2)
     a  b  c
2001 1  6  2
2002 2  7  4
2003 3  8  6
2004 4  9  8
2005 5 10 10
```

You really need to understand environments and evaluation frames to use `transform()` - well you can't you'd need to learn to use `eval()`, which is what `transform()` calls internally, and specify the correct values for `envir` (the environment in which to evaluate), and `enclos` the enclosure. See `?eval`.

Comment: Thanks for the warning! I didn't know about it -- I'm still using R 2.15.2 from October.  Over the years I've grown to love transform when working with dataframes. Esp. with longer names, all those $ and [] expressions can get unwieldy.  Great idea of the developers to get me addicted for years and to now take away the drug. ;-)

Comment: To be fare these things never worked reliably and the advice for programming was always to use `$` and `[`.

Comment: What I meant by "unwieldy expressions" in my comment was my usual way for assignments: `foo[bar] <- foo[another.col] + another.df[whatever.col]` etc.  I don't know yet if I like your cbind version better.  It's a bit more concise, but for zoo, there's this taking apart & putting together in order to work with the coredata.

Comment: Right, but you only write the function once :-)

Comment: Too bad I never got the memo...  I've seen `transform` being happily used in examples all around the web and there wasn't any warning in the documentation back then. Having used some Common Lisp before, I always had thought of `transform` as some syntactic sugar similar to `with-slots` (which is safe to use).

Comment: Check out the still experimental plyrmr package on github. The goal of the package is to process large data sets, but in the process I developed two approximate replacements from transform and subset, called where and select, that should avoid this pitfall. From the tutorial: > find.bad.ass.cars.plyrmr = function(data, threshold) where(select(data, carb.per.cyl =carb/cyl, .replace=F), carb.per.cyl >= threshold)
> find.bad.ass.cars.plyrmr(mtcars, 1)
It works. This was very advanced R programming for me and I am sure there will be some problems, but at least I gave it a try.

Comment: I would advise against $ for programming because it accepts prefixes, if they are ambiguous bugs can occur aplenty.